# A question about local extreme value

Tags: calculus

Here is the question:
Suppose that $c$ is a critical point for $f$ and $f′(x)>0$ for $x≠c$. If $f(c)$ is a local maximum, then $f$ is not continuous at $c.$

I know it is true, but I don't know how to prove it logically. Would someone give some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous at $c$, then $f$ would be (strictly) increasing in the neighbourhood of $c$. This contradicts the local maximum property.

Answer (score 0):

Since $c$ is a local maximum, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $f(x)\le f(c)$.

Take $x=c+\delta/2$ and apply the mean value theorem:
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(y)
$$
for some $y\in(c,x)$.